# Bootstrap 3.x - force column widths to calculate based on screen width and not parent div width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap's grid system, and have laid out a page to works well on both mobile and desktop browsers by using appropriate col-md-x and col-sm-x classes in various elements.

My issue is that I want to specify a maximum width of several sections on my page.

If I use a container and specify a col-md-8 for example, then all of the controls, divs, etc. inside the container get resized, because bootstrap uses percentages to calculate the column sizes and inside the col-md-8 div, a col-md-6 div will only be col-md-(6/8) wide.

This causes a problem for other parts of the page that are full width, a div of col-md-6 won't be the same width and that I can't line up all of the columns.

So, is there a way to get bootstrap to always calculate the col-md-x column sizes based on the width of the screen and not the parent container?

Comment: Well, what you describe is the way it was supposed to work. Using the viewport width would cause more problems than what it would solve. If you post some code I might be able to help you out with what you are trying to achieve. Have you thought of using several containers with different heights?

Comment: Concerning your example, the correct class to use inside the col-md-8 column to get 'viewport 50%' would be a nested col-md-9 class (3/4 of col-md-8) https://jsfiddle.net/eo8rzdae/